# Is it practical to use self signed certificate to encrypt connection for Web API?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, restful-architecture

We have RESTFul Web Api using OAuth2 for authentication. Is it practical to use self signed certificate for SSL/TLS encryption? We provide .Net/Java SDK where the certificate validation error for not being a trusted CA issued will be ignored, so the customers won't see any error unless he/she tries to call the Api directly from HTTP request. This solution looks good to us but are there any risks or disadvantages?

Comment: Not sure why you think this is not a programming issue. Programming is not all about code and programmers are not just coders.  I see a lot of discussions on StackOverflow talking about the engineering methodology of computer science without a single line of code, and they are just great and very helpful for programmers.

Comment: @LouisYang: while I agree with you  a better site for this kind of questions (i.e. secure design) might be security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich I've been getting a lot of help from SO for the past several years (usually by search engines) but have no idea of there're specialized sites. That's a shame. Actually this is the first question I asked on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation of the certificate is done to make sure that the client is talking to the expected server, i.e. authentication. **Validation is the essential part of defending against man in the middle attacks**, i.e. against an attacker in the path of the traffic doing sniffing and modifying the data.

Thus while you can use self-signed certificates instead of certificates signed by a publicly trusted CA you still need to properly validate the certificates and **not simply disable validation.** For self-signed certificates this can be done by checking if the fingerprint of the certificate or its public key matches the expectation. It would not be enough to just check the subject of the certificate because an attacker could easily create certificates with the same subject and use it inside attacks.

For more information on how to do this properly including sample code see [OWASP: Certificate and Public Key Pinnning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning).

Comment: Thank a lot. We do check the public key of the self-signed certificate in the SDK. The validation error I mentioned in the question is referring to the server certificate is not issued by a trusted CA. I'm not familiar with Java yet, but .Net/C# does raise validation error if the certificate from sever isn't issued by a trusted CA. Are there any other reasons we shouldn't use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @LouisYang: a self-signed certificate is fine if validated properly, i.e. by knowing which certificate to expect up-front and checking if the public key matches the expected one. The main reason we have public CA's trusted by the browsers is that we usually don't know which certificate to expect and thus need to derive the trust by using trusted issuers.

Comment: There's always the [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) project, which will let you get your cert signed for free. I use it in my servers.